# Maven custom file structure

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-nar-plugin

I want to create a specific custom file structure for developping and I want to  know if it could be done with maven.

It is important to mention that i am using c++ for programming language and the [*Maven-nar-plugin*](http://maven-nar.github.io)

I want to be able run a command like : *mvn dependency:resolve* and the required librairies would go in the folder *Librairies*. That way all i would have to do is link the *include* folder of a library to my project in Visual Studio.

I dont want to compile with maven I just want to use it's dependency manager

I know you can change the SourceDirectory but can you change where the Librairies will be installed ?

Workspace
|
|-- Project1
|      |-- pom.xml
|
|-- Project2
|      |-- pom.xml
|
|-- Librairies
     |-- ExempleLib-V-2.0
     |         |-- Include
     |         |-- lib
     |
     |-- ExempleLib-V-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using *maven-dependency-plugin*.

The following code will take every dependency and copy it over to the *Librairies* folder.
You could even use *unpack-dependencies* instead of *copy-dependencies* to directly unpack the dependency in the folder

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                  ../Libraries
                </outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can tell maven that your local repository is in this Librairies directory rather than in ~/.m2/repository

You can pass parameter maven.repo.local when launching it and it will download everything there

mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=Librairies clean install

Comment: this could be a way to do it but i am also using maven for other java applications so the *Libraries* folder would also be filled with non c++ related package and package i dont even use in those projects

Comment: This would only apply when you launch mvn with this flag. So just use the flag when you want to download the dependencies and never use it again...